# Left and right justify grid elements and stretching center column on a button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Three textBlocks are on a button. It is desired to have Column 0 and 2 textBlocks anchored at the left and right edges of the button respectively while column 1 textblock takes up the excess space. How can this be accomplished?

```
<Grid Width="150" Height="50">
    <Button 
            Style="{StaticResource GrayStyleButton}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Text="+">
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Text="Page1_b2">
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Text="+">
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could have the images and textblock inside a stackpanel (`Orientation="Horizontal"`), one image with `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`, the textblock with `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` and the other image with `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`.

Comment: You just need to add `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to the `Button` element. The way you've got the XAML now, the `Grid` that's a child of the `Button` is automatically resizing to fit its contents. So while the columns 0 and 2 stay the same size, and column 1 always stretches to use the remaining space in the `Grid`, the `Grid` itself is changing size according to the length of the text. Setting the `Button.HorizontalContentAlignment` property will tell the `Button` to always make the `Grid` as large as it can be in the `Button`.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I had to remove the "StaticResource GrayStyleButton" reference to get HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" to work. It appears the static resource was overriding the stretch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" for both button and Grid

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid Width="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                               FontSize="12"
                               Text="+" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                               FontSize="12"
                               Text="Page1_b2" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                               FontSize="12"
                               Text="+" />
                </Grid>
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid Width="150" Height="50">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource GrayStyleButton}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Image Style="{StaticResource BlockArrowLeftWhite}"
                   Height="{StaticResource fontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            </Image>

            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource fontSize}" Text="Page1_b2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

            <Image Style="{StaticResource BlockArrowLeft}" Height="{StaticResource fontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            </Image>

        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

I hope that you took proper margin values and other indentation properties in you static style resources.